# Callling Solana contract functions or converting my eth base code to Solana base code

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, ethereum

Here is some similar code to my old code that I am using for my eth base contracts.

I want to convert this existing code into a Solana base contract. I have mentioned all my questions in the comments of my code; please help me if you can.

For example you can see my first comment. This was the contract ABI file; I don't know what to use for Solana contract but I am using this for my eth contract. Please let me know if this is something similar like an IDL file for Solana anchor base projects, and please let me know what to use if we are not using anchor framework.

```
const Web3 = require("web3")

/*
    This was the contract ABI file 
    i dont know what to use for solana contract but i am using this
    for my eth contract please let me know if this is something similar like IDL
    file for solana anchor base projects and please please let me know 
    what to use if we are not using anchor framework 
*/
const abiFile = require("./my-abi-file.json")
const infuraMainNetUrl = "myInfuraMainNetUrl"

// pulicWalletAddressOfUser is wallet public address of a user 
// which can be an eth wallet like metamask
const getNfts = async (pulicWalletAddressOfUser) => {
    try {

        /*
            Thses are different contract addresses i need to check against for
            available NFTs and user balance. i dont know is this same as infura
            program ids or please correct me if i am wrong
        */
        const contractAddresses = [
            "contractAddressA",
            "contractAddressB",
            "contractAddressC"
        ]
        const web3 = new Web3(infuraMainNetUrl)
        for (let contractAddress of contractAddresses) {


            /**
             * Here i am initializing my contract with my abi file and 
             * and contract address please let mr know ho i shuold initailze it with 
             * my solana contract
             */
            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiFile, contractAddress)
            
            /**
             * Here i am calling balanceOf from the contract i want to
             * achieve the same with solana 
             * 
            */
            const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(pulicWalletAddressOfUser).call()
            const tokenIds = [];
            for( let i = 0; i < balance; ++i ){
            /**
             * Here i am calling balanceOf from the contract i want to
             * achieve the same with solana here as well
             * 
            */
              const tokenId = await contract.methods.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(pulicWalletAddressOfUser, i ).call()
              tokenIds.push( tokenId );
            }

            for (let tokenId of tokenIds ) {

                /**
                 * I am calling tokenURI from contract to get token meatadata url 
                 * i want to achieve the same for solana contract as i am doing here
                 * for my eth base contracts 
                */
                const tokenMetadataUrl = await contract.methods.tokenURI(tokenId).call()
                console.log("Token metadata url:", tokenMetadataUrl)
            }
        }

  
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error:", err.message)
    }
}

(async () => {
    console.log("Calling function to get nfts meta data")
    const someUserWalletPublicAddress = "0xb09b078bB272942E4398C56247aA317E6078bdbE"
    getNfts(mikeyPublicAddress)
})()
```